# Excel sort in ascending order days and hours since an event

Tags: excel, sorting

I have data in the format x hours y days since an event that looks like so:

```
0 days 2 hours
5 days 1 hour
0 days 0 hours
0 days 0 hours
0 days 0 hours
0 days 0 hours
```

I want to sort these cells in ascending order by length of time in Excel, but I can't see how to do it.

Comment: you could use the "text to columns" feature on the data tab using so the unit of measure and integer values are in separate columns then sort.

Comment: That works well to sort the first value, but how do I sort the hours within each day?

Comment: Select range. go to data tab and sort.  you should be allowed to sort on multiple columns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They say a picture is worth a 1000 words.

Data tab, sort add a level and sort by days/hours (I added column headers you don't have to have them)

Be sure to select all COLUMNS which need to be sorted. If you don't data in columns E+ will not be sorted with the respective data!!!

[image]